# Left and right text in header without Fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Is there a way to write a header with left- and right-aligned text without using the package Fancyhdr?

Comment: Sure, you can redefine `\@oddhead` etc manually. But why don't you want use fancyhdr?

Comment: You can use `titleps`, a companion to the `titlesec` package.

Comment: `\makeatletter  \newcommand\@oddhead{left\hfill right}` is all you need but why not use `fancyhdr` which does the same, but with a nicer interface?

Comment: Package `scrlayer-scrpage` does a nice job as well. It is part of the KOMA-bundle.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer: I have to do it for a school assignment and I´m not sure if we´re allowed to use external packages.                                               Bernard: Thanks!                                                    David Carlisle: Thank you! I´ll try using that.             Johannes_B: Thank you!

Comment: There are so many packages that expand the possibilities of the kernel. Invent the wheel every single time? No, that is what packages are for. What would you do without `graphicx` (and `graphics`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defined some macros for easier access to the headers.  You have to use the `twoside` option of the documentclass to actually distinguish between odd and even pages (without all pages are treated as odd).

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% Use some ridicolouosly small paper for demonstration
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\oddhead[1]{\gdef\@oddhead{\reset@font#1}}
\newcommand\evenhead[1]{\gdef\@evenhead{\reset@font#1}}
\newcommand\oddfoot[1]{\gdef\@oddfoot{\reset@font#1}}
\newcommand\evenfoot[1]{\gdef\@evenfoot{\reset@font#1}}
\makeatother

\oddhead{\hfil Some header on odd pages\hfil}
\evenhead{\hfil Some header on even pages\hfil}
\oddfoot{\hfil Some footer on odd pages\hfil}
\evenfoot{\hfil Some footer on even pages\hfil}

\begin{document}

Odd page

\clearpage

Even page

\end{document}
```

> [image]
>
> [image]